# Avoid Remote command OS Injection in Java Web Application

Tags: java, security, zap

We are running ZAP tool from OWSAP to check the security vulnerabilities in our application. The ZAP tool reported many Issues like Path traversal, Cross site scripting, OS command Injection. Here I did not understand what is exactly happening when OS command is executed in our application.
The below is an example from our project which is reported while uploading file.

```
http://<<IpAddr>>:<<port>>/filedsMgr/upload/fileupload?/?fileSize=837259
%7Ctimeout+%2FT+%7B0%7D
```

In the above url the attack is performed on the "filesize" parameter and the attack is "837259|timeout /T {0}".
As per the description given by OWASP, I understood that this is timeout command performed by ZAP tool, but I did not understand, how it is related to My application.

Could any please tell me what exactly it is and how to prevent this attack?

Comment: validate incoming param ```fileSize```, tryto cast to ```int``` or ```long``` with try-catch and throw exception

Comment: Thank you @EvgenyLebedev, So we don't need to worry about timeout os command?

Comment: of course, timeouts - next issue, you must use timeouts for all connections

Comment: "you must use timeouts for all connections" this sentence I did not understand. that is the attack done by ZAP tool

Comment: server side must use timeouts for connection handling (configuration of your application server or application)

Comment: Yes@EvgenyLebedev, We have configured our application with 30 mins timeout

Answer (score 0):

For example: you have REST controller with method fileUpload and bindings for `/file-upload/{fileSize}`:

code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file-upload/{fileSize}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Response fileUpload(@PathVariable int fileSize) {
    //...
}
```

if some villain will send you additional data for your fileSize path param
this method will throw exception. because it will be invalid integer value: `837259%7Ctimeout+%2FT+%7B0%7D`

also recommended:

1. Use principle: do not trust client

   - what is not allowed -> denied
   - check all input arguments (especially strings)
2. Use timeouts for all external communications